# Нужно специально мутировать входной массив

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

В задаче требуется нарочно мутировать входящий массив в функцию.

```
function replaceItemsAndMutate(arr, item, replaceItem) {

}

const array = ['qwerty',2,3,7,56,3]
replaceItemsAndMutate(array, 3, 'replaced')
console.log(array) // ['qwerty',2,'replaced',7,56, 'replaced]
```

Я понимаю как сделать так что бы не мутировал, но мне нужно именно с мутацией.

```
function replaceWithoutMutating(arr, item, replaceItem) {
  const newArray = arr.map((el) => {
    if (el === item) el = replaceItem;
    return el;
  });
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: я пытался через forEach и по какой-то причине console.log() до и после вызова функции  такойже

Comment: Наверно писали `if (el === item) el = replaceItem;`  внутри forEach?) Это то же самое,        что `3 = replaceItem;` потому и не будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = ['qwerty', 2, 3, 7, 56, 3];
replaceItemsAndMutate(array, 3, 'replaced');
console.log(array);

function replaceItemsAndMutate(arr, item, replaceItem) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === item) arr[i] = replaceItem;
  }
}
```

```css
code { white-space: nowrap !important }
```

Через `forEach` будет так:

```
arr.forEach((el, i) => {
  if (el === item) arr[i] = replaceItem;
});
```